# How to conform to MutableCollection?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have trouble finding documentation on how to conform to [`MutableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mutablecollection). Google is completely empty on that topic.

**Example**, I want to add conformance for [`GMSPath`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_path)/[`GMSMutablePath`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_mutable_path):

```
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps

extension GMSPath: RandomAccessCollection {

    public var startIndex: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public var endIndex: Int {
        return count
    }

    public func index(before i: Int) -> Int {
        return i-1
    }

    public func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return i+1
    }

    public subscript(position: Int) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return coordinate(at: UInt(position))
    }
}

extension GMSMutablePath: MutableCollection {  // Error!

    public override subscript(position: Int) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        get {
            return coordinate(at: UInt(position))
        }
        set {
            replaceCoordinate(at: UInt(position), with: newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

> Error: Type 'GMSMutablePath' does not conform to a) 'MutableIndexable', b) 'MutableCollection'.

Documentation for [`MutableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mutablecollection) states:

> To add conformance to the MutableCollection protocol to your own custom collection, upgrade your type’s subscript to support both read and write access.

I did that.

`MutableCollection` inherits from `MutableIndexable`, the docs stating:

> In most cases, it’s best to ignore this protocol and use the MutableCollection protocol instead, because it has a more complete interface.

Hm?

Comment: Because MutableCollection is a subtype of MutableIndexable, you must conform to MutableIndexable to be conferment to MutableCollection

Comment: Any hints what to implement exactly? With default implementations etc. you never know what you need to implement. And the docs are not clear at all.

Comment: The default implementations are listed in the doc you need to imponent at least everything but those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that I was also conforming to `RandomAccessCollection` instead of just `Collection`/`MutableCollection`. In that case, contrary to what the docs promise, we have to do more than just provide a subscript setter. Specifically, the slice subscripts need to be implemented.

I ended up with the following. The typaliases are necessary because the compiler can't always seem to infer them.

```
 extension GMSPath: RandomAccessCollection {

    public typealias Index = Int
    public typealias Indices = DefaultRandomAccessIndices<GMSPath>

    public var startIndex: Index {
        return 0
    }

    public var endIndex: Index {
        return count
    }

    public func index(before i: Index) -> Index {
        return i-1
    }

    public func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        return i+1
    }

    public subscript(position: Index) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return coordinate(at: UInt(position))
    }
}

extension GMSMutablePath: MutableCollection {

    public subscript(bounds: Range<Index>) -> RandomAccessSlice<GMSPath> {
        get { return .init(base: self, bounds: bounds) }
        set {
            assert(newValue.count == bounds.count)
            newValue.enumerated().forEach { self[$0] = $1 }
        }
    }

    public override subscript(position: Index) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        get { return coordinate(at: UInt(position)) }
        set { replaceCoordinate(at: UInt(position), with: newValue) }
    }
}
```

With Swift's conditional default protocol implementations, I find it really hard to find out what exactly needs to be implemented.